# JSON.Net Serializing Derived Classes

Tags: c#, json, serialization, json.net

To work with a recipe webservice I'm developing, I have the following classes to hold and serialize recipe data:

```
class Recipe {

    public string RecipeId { get; private set; }

    public string UserId { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }

    public IList<string> IngredientsList { get; set; }

    public List<Group<string, Ingredient>> IngredientsWithHeaders { get; set; }
    public List<Group<string, string>> InstructionsWithHeaders { get; set; }

    public List<string> Notes { get; set; }
    public ISet<string> Tags { get; set; }
    public int Yield { get; set; }

    public Recipe(string recipeId)
    {
        RecipeId = recipeId;
        IngredientsWithHeaders = new List<Group<string,Ingredient>>();
        InstructionsWithHeaders = new List<Group<string, string>>();
        IngredientsList = new List<string>();
    }

    public byte[] Image { get; set; }
}

class Ingredient
{
    public string Quantity { get; set; }
    public string Modifier { get; set; }
    public string Unit { get; set; }
    public string IngredientName { get; set; }
    public string Preparation { get; set; }

    public Ingredient(string[] line)
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(line.ElementAt(0)))
        {
            Quantity = line.ElementAt(0);
        }
        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(line.ElementAt(1)))
        {
            Unit = line.ElementAt(1);
        }
        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(line.ElementAt(2)))
        {
            IngredientName = line.ElementAt(2);
        }
        if(line.Length>3)
        {
            Preparation = line.Last();
        }
    }
}

class Group<K, T> : ObservableCollection<T>
{
    public K Key { get; set; }

    public Group(K key, IEnumerable<T> items) : base(items)
    {
        Key = key;
        Debug.WriteLine(key);
    }
}
```

The JSON output I am getting for the `List<Group<string, Ingredient>>` is

```
{
"IngredientsWithHeaders": [
    [
        {
            "Quantity": "3",
            "Modifier": null,
            "Unit": "tbsp",
            "IngredientName": "butter",
            "Preparation": null
        },
        {
            "Quantity": "1",
            "Modifier": null,
            "Unit": "16 oz. bag",
            "IngredientName": "marshmallows",
            "Preparation": null
        },
        {
            "Quantity": "2/3",
            "Modifier": null,
            "Unit": "cup",
            "IngredientName": "dry cake mix",
            "Preparation": null
        },
        {
            "Quantity": "6",
            "Modifier": null,
            "Unit": "cups",
            "IngredientName": "crispy rice cereal",
            "Preparation": null
        },
        {
            "Quantity": "1",
            "Modifier": null,
            "Unit": "container",
            "IngredientName": "sprinkles",
            "Preparation": "optional"
        }
        ]
    ]
}
```

and what I would like to be getting is more along the lines of

```
{
"IngredientsWithHeaders": [
    {
        "Group": {
            "Header": "BlankHeader",
            "Items": [
                {
                    "Quantity": "3",
                    "Modifier": null,
                    "Unit": "tbsp",
                    "IngredientName": "butter",
                    "Preparation": null
                },
                {
                    "Quantity": "1",
                    "Modifier": null,
                    "Unit": "16 oz. bag",
                    "IngredientName": "marshmallows",
                    "Preparation": null
                },
                {
                    "Quantity": "2/3",
                    "Modifier": null,
                    "Unit": "cup",
                    "IngredientName": "dry cake mix",
                    "Preparation": null
                },
                {
                    "Quantity": "6",
                    "Modifier": null,
                    "Unit": "cups",
                    "IngredientName": "crispy rice cereal",
                    "Preparation": null
                },
                {
                    "Quantity": "1",
                    "Modifier": null,
                    "Unit": "container",
                    "IngredientName": "sprinkles",
                    "Preparation": "optional"
                }
                ]
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Do I need to write a custom serializer? If so, how do I go about casting an object to a parameterized Group without knowing if it is

```
Group<string, Ingredient>
```

or

```
Group<string, string>
```

?

Comment: The JSON you want is invalid.  Try uploading it to http://jsonlint.com/ and you will get an error.  A JSON container can be either an object (an unordered set of name/value pairs) or an array -- but not both.  Can you give an example of the JSON you want that is valid, according to http://jsonlint.com/?

Comment: My mistake, edit with more specific JSON forthcoming.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue here is that your `Group<K, T>` is a collection that also has properties.  Since a JSON container can either be an array (with no properties) or an object (with named key/value pairs), a collection with custom properties cannot be mapped automatically to either without data loss.  Json.NET (and all other serializers AFAIK) choose to map the items not the custom properties.

You have a couple ways to deal with this:

1. Write your own custom [`JsonConverter`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonConverter.htm).  You can determine the generic arguments using reflection along the lines of [Json.Net returns Empty Brackets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30030398/json-net-returns-empty-brackets/30035908#30035908).
2. Mark your `Group<K, T>` with [`[JsonObject]`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/JsonObjectAttributeOverrideIEnumerable.htm).

The second option seems simplest, and would look like:

```
[JsonObject(MemberSerialization = MemberSerialization.OptIn)] // OptIn to omit the properties of the base class,  e.g. Count
class Group<K, T> : ObservableCollection<T>
{
    [JsonProperty("Header")]
    public K Key { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("Items")]
    IEnumerable<T> Values
    {
        get
        {
            foreach (var item in this)
                yield return item;
        }
        set
        {
            if (value != null)
                foreach (var item in value)
                    Add(item);
        }
    }

    public Group(K Header, IEnumerable<T> Items) // Since there is no default constructor, argument names should match JSON property names.
        : base(Items)
    {
        Key = Header;
    }
}
```

Incidentally, you have another problem -- your `Ingredient` class does not have a default constructor, and its single parameterized throws a `NullReferenceException` if the `line` argument is null.  In the absence of a default constructor Json.NET will call the single parameterized constructor, mapping JSON object values to constructor arguments by name.  Thus, deserialization throws an exception.

You have a few ways to deal with this:

1. Add a public default constructor.
2. Add a *private* default constructor and mark it with [`[JsonConstructor]`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonConstructorAttribute.htm):

   ```
   [JsonConstructor]
   Ingredient() { }
   ```
3. Add a *private* default constructor and deserialize with [`ConstructorHandling.AllowNonPublicDefaultConstructor`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_ConstructorHandling.htm):

   ```
   var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings { ConstructorHandling = ConstructorHandling.AllowNonPublicDefaultConstructor };
   var recipe = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Recipe>(json, settings);
   ```
4. Add an `if (line != null)` check in the constructor.  (Not really recommended.  Instead your constructor should explicitly throw an `ArgumentNullException`.)

Having done this, you will gt JSON that looks like:

```
{
  "IngredientsWithHeaders": [
    {
      "Header": "BlankHeader",
      "Items": [
        {
          "Quantity": "3",
          "Modifier": null,
          "Unit": "tbsp",
          "IngredientName": "butter",
          "Preparation": null
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
}
```

Your proposed JSON has an extra level of nesting with

```
{
"IngredientsWithHeaders": [
    {
        "Group": {
            "Header": "BlankHeader",
```

This extra `"Group"` object is unnecessary.

Comment: I just implemented these changes and saw an immediate difference. Thanks for addressing the extra level of nesting - I knew my example of what I wanted wasn't quite optimal, but I wasn't sure exactly what it should look like.