# Couchbase Lite Doc missing properties

Tags: c#, json, xamarin, couchbase, couchbase-lite

I've been using Couchbase Lite in a cross-platform (Xamarin) app project as a local datastore. I have been retrieving objects from an Amazon Web-service backend, serialized using Newtonsoft JSON. Everything in my object serializes correctly since the answer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32062025/json-net-serializing-derived-classes) question I asked a couple weeks ago. However, adding the "group" properties of my recipes to a document in couchbase lite has been unsuccessful. No exceptions are thrown on saving the doc, but the "IngredientsWithHeaders" and "InstructionsWithHeaders" both return null when the doc is retrieved from the database. The following is save/retrieval code:

```
public void SaveRecipe (Recipe recipe)
    {
        var document = db.GetDocument (recipe.RecipeId);
        var properties = new Dictionary<string, object> (){
            { "UserId",recipe.UserId },
            { "Title",recipe.Title },
            { "IngredientsList",recipe.IngredientsList },
            { "Notes",recipe.Notes },
            { "Tags",recipe.Tags },
            { "Yield",recipe.Yield },
            { "IngredientsWithHeaders",recipe.IngredientsWithHeaders },
            { "InstructionsWithHeaders",recipe.InstructionsWithHeaders }
        };
        var rev = document.PutProperties(properties);
        Debug.Assert (rev != null, "Revision is null");
        var newRev = document.CurrentRevision.CreateRevision ();
        newRev.SetAttachment ("image.jpg", "image/jpeg", recipe.Image);
        newRev.Save ();
    }

public IEnumerable<Recipe> GetRecipes ()
    {
        var query = db.CreateAllDocumentsQuery ();
        query.AllDocsMode = AllDocsMode.AllDocs;
        var rows = query.Run ();
        Debug.WriteLine ("Recipes in Query: "+rows.Count);
        return rows.Select (recipe => ToRecipe (recipe.Document));
    }

private Recipe ToRecipe(Document doc){
        Recipe recipe = new Recipe(doc.Id);
        recipe.UserId = doc.GetProperty<string> ("UserId");
        recipe.Title = doc.GetProperty<string> ("Title");
        recipe.IngredientsList = doc.GetProperty<List<string>> ("IngredientsList");
        recipe.Notes = doc.GetProperty<List<string>> ("Notes");
        recipe.Tags = doc.GetProperty<ISet<string>> ("Tags");
        recipe.Yield = doc.GetProperty<int> ("Yield");
        recipe.IngredientsWithHeaders = doc.GetProperty<List<Group<string,IngredientJson>>> ("IngredientsWithHeaders");
        recipe.InstructionsWithHeaders = doc.GetProperty<List<Group<string,string>>> ("InstructionsWithHeaders");
        var rev = doc.CurrentRevision;
        var image = rev.GetAttachment ("image.jpg");
        if (image != null) {
            Debug.WriteLine ("There is an image here");
            recipe.Image = image.Content.ToArray();
        }
        return recipe;
    }
```

Comment: It sounds exactly like the serialization problem you mentioned in your last question.  Which approach did you take to solve it?  I would suggest using `Dictionary` instead of `Group`

Comment: I did consider that, but it seems to be serializing correctly into the couchbase lite database. It just doesn't deserialize into the desired type, for some reason.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing the `ToRecipe()` method to the following solved the problem:

```
private Recipe ToRecipe(Document doc){
    Recipe recipe = new Recipe(doc.Id);
    recipe.UserId = doc.GetProperty<string> ("UserId");
    recipe.Title = doc.GetProperty<string> ("Title");
    recipe.IngredientsList = doc.GetProperty<List<string>> ("IngredientsList");
    recipe.Notes = doc.GetProperty<List<string>> ("Notes");
    recipe.Tags = doc.GetProperty<ISet<string>> ("Tags");
    recipe.Yield = doc.GetProperty<int> ("Yield");
    recipe.IngredientsWithHeaders = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Group<string, IngredientJson>>>(doc.GetProperty ("IngredientsWithHeaders").ToString());

    recipe.InstructionsWithHeaders = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Group<string, string>>>(doc.GetProperty("InstructionsWithHeaders").ToString());

    var rev = doc.CurrentRevision;
    var image = rev.GetAttachment ("image.jpg");
    if (image != null) {
        Debug.WriteLine ("There is an image here");
        recipe.Image = image.Content.ToArray();
    }
    return recipe;
}
```