# How do I serialize ObservableCollection-derived class to and from JSON?

Tags: c#, json, xamarin.android

For .NET.  I've tried a lot of different things, but nothing seems to work.  Requirements:

1. The T of ObservableCollection<T> is an ISerializable
2. The ObservableCollection-derived-class ideally is also an ISerializable
3. For this context, being an ISerializable = uses only ISerializable technique for serialization, not reflected properties

Environment is Xamarin for Android, I'd prefer to use either JSON.NET or DataContractJsonSerializer.  Example uses Newtonsoft 9.0.1

With code like this:

```
[Serializable]
[KnownType(typeof(ObservableCollectionSerializable.Item))]
public class ObservableCollectionSerializable : 
    ObservableCollection<ObservableCollectionSerializable.Item>
{
    [Serializable]
    public class Item : ISerializable
    {
        readonly string value;

        public Item(string value) { this.value = value; }

        public Item(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context)
        {
            value = info.GetString("value");
        }

        public void GetObjectData(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context)
        {
            info.AddValue("value", value);
        }
    }
}
```

Invoked like this:

```
            var _item = new Test.ObservableCollectionSerializable.Item("test1");
            var c = new Test.ObservableCollectionSerializable();

            c.Add(_item);

            var serializer = new Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer();
            serializer.ContractResolver = new Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.DefaultContractResolver()
            {
                //IgnoreSerializableInterface = false // not available
            };
            var stringWriter = new StringWriter();

            serializer.Serialize(stringWriter, c);

            var json = stringWriter.ToString();                

            var stringReader = new StringReader(json);

            var c2 = (Test.ObservableCollectionSerializable)
                serializer.Deserialize(stringReader, typeof(Test.ObservableCollectionSerializable));

            var item = c2[0];
```

Results are:

- "json" variable always ends up "[{}]" - empty
- ISerialize-based methods are never called
- serializer.Deserialize call always throws exception "Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException: Unable to find a constructor to use for type Notos.App.UI.Android.Test.ObservableCollectionSerializable+Item. A class should either have a default constructor, one constructor with arguments or a constructor marked with the JsonConstructor attribute. Path '[0]', line 1, position 3"

Comment: cant you just convert your `ObservableCollection<T>` to `T[]` and then serialize it ?

Comment: JSON.NET works just fine for this. What didn't work for you?

Comment: 1) Can you share a [mcve] for this problem?  2) If using Json.NET, be sure that you have not set [`DefaultContractResolver.IgnoreSerializableInterface = true`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/P_Newtonsoft_Json_Serialization_DefaultContractResolver_IgnoreSerializableInterface.htm).  3) If your custom collection also has properties, see [How to serialize/deserialize a custom collection with additional properties using Json.Net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14383736) or [JSON.Net Serializing Derived Classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32062025).

Comment: @dbc IgnoreSerializableInterface property was not available for me.  @Nudity even attempting as `T[]` json variable ends up empty

Comment: The example code works fine in my environment. I see the value of json as `[{"value":"test1"}]`

Comment: @RQDQ good to know; are you in Xamarin for Android, or elsewhere?

Comment: What version and implementation of Json.NET for xamarin are you using?

Comment: @dbc it's 9.0.1 targetframework="monoandroid60".  The path includes "portable-net45+wp80+win8+wpa81".  Is it possible a dependent assembly is pulling in an older version and messing up things?

Comment: You could do `Console.WriteLine("Json.NET version: " + typeof(JsonSerializer).Assembly.FullName);` to be sure.  Also, Newtonsoft doesn't have a xamarin build, does it?  What build are you using?

Comment: Verified, using 9.0.0 assembly.  Correct, no Xamarin build, this one seems to be the PCL build for .NET 4.5

Comment: `IgnoreSerializableInterface` and `IgnoreSerializableAttribute` are not available for the `DOTNET || PORTABLE || PORTABLE40` builds.  See the [reference source](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/blob/master/Src/Newtonsoft.Json/Serialization/DefaultContractResolver.cs#L169).   Maybe try this instead?  https://components.xamarin.com/view/json.net

Comment: @dbc good insight.  I tried the 7.0 one hosted as a Xamarin component (verified with assembly.FullName) and same result.  It appears PCL(and legacy Android) build may currently exclude ISerialization support?

Comment: @Malachi - xamarin claims to have ISerializable: https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/System.Runtime.Serialization.ISerializable/  so I don't know why the xamarin component doesn't have it.  Sorry I can't be more help.  Maybe there's some sort of security issue?  See here https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.isafeserializationdata(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @dbc for real.  I have used ISerializable for other scenarios in Xamarin/Mono.  Based on our comments, I tried brute forcing the non-PCL net45 newtonsoft build and actually it works!  I'd consider this a workaround not a solution since updates will probably break it